# How can I get Spotify to scale properly on HiDPI?

Tags: release-hera, hidpi, camera, surface-tablet, spotify

So I downloaded spotify through snap and the client works fine except it doesn't have any option to scale to my 3000x2000 display on my surface book. I saw a post that fixes the issue [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Linux-Ubuntu-Scaling-Issue/td-p/4524721)

The thing im worried about is that I get this response from my terminal

```
2019/12/18 16:18:56.427654 cmd_run.go:884: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: failed to verify SELinux context of /home/l3ruce/snap: exec: "matchpathcon": executable file not found in $PATH
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[1218/161856.864264:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```

This does work however I can not use the terminal unless I open a different tab and if I close that tab or the terminal itself then spotify closes. I just want to be sure that it is ok to run this command every time I launch spotify or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the Snap version of Spotify, but I just installed the [Flatpak version from Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.spotify.Client) and it works with scaling out of the box. That should be much easier than trying to manually edit config files!

To install Spotify from Flatpak:

1. Visit the [Spotify page on Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.spotify.Client)
2. Click the **Install** button on the web page
3. Depending on your browser, Sideload may open automatically. If not, choose to open the downloaded file with **Sideload**.
4. Read and agree to the implications of installing an untrusted app from Flatpak.

If this is the first Flatpak app you've installed, it might not show up in the Applications Menu until you log out and back in—future Flatpak apps will show up instantly. You can then uninstall the snap version from the Terminal using `snap remove spotify`.

It's typically recommended to use Flatpak apps on elementary OS instead of snap or .deb, because elementary has [officially backed Flatpak](https://blog.elementary.io/elementary-appcenter-flatpak/), elementary OS supports Flatpak out of the box, and elementary developers have put [significant work into](https://blog.elementary.io/updates-for-october-2019/) making sure it's easy to install and update Flatpak apps without having to use a Terminal.